# Play media file and append it in the same time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing media player, which should be able to play audio from Internet. As I've noticed, standard `MediaPlayer` is quite unstable when playing remote content: It is often falls or stops playback with no reason.
On the other side, I want to implement media caching. But I haven't found any way to get buffered content from `MediaPlayer` to save it somewhere on device.

So, I'd like to implement buffering for myself and make `MediaPlayer` play only local media. The first way I see is to download enough piece of media to a file, start playing this file via `MediaPlayer` and continue downloading the rest of media (with pausing when not enough media downloaded and processing other events like that).

The question is: it is possible to play file and append it in the same time? Now I only have `IllegalStateExceptions` when calling `MediaPlayer`'s `setDataSource`

**UPD**

`IllegalStateException` was caused by invalid logic. MediaPlayer is playing now.

But the other issue appeared.

So, first 5% of track is downloaded, MediaPlayer start playing, play these 5% and then stops. Is it a way to keep playing?

Starting playback is trivial:

```
private void startPlayback(final File file) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
        mPlayer.setDataSource(fs.getFD());
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(e);
    }
}
```

May be there is other stream type useful for this case?

Comment: are u releasing mediaplayer before setDataSource method .... since file is in downloading mode , it may have been changed ..and that's why you are getting the IllegalstateException

Comment: Thanks! It was application logic problem. Not release, but similar. There is another issue now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simultaneous appending and playing file work on some devices and don't work on others. So, it is not a solution. I tried many ways to implement own buffering and playback (see [Best practices for audio streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405017/best-practices-for-audio-streaming)) and decided to use JellyBean Media API (as I'm developing for JB-device). For pre-JB devices this question is still open

Comment: Can u explain how have you implemented this feature in JB devices, if you have implemented it?