# Radio Streaming fails in some URLs

Tags: android, audio, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I have succesfully used Media Player to play many Url's that provide Audio/Radio streaming, but I have found some particular cases in which it doesn't work,
Media Player never reach onPrepared. I have test with VLC they play well are in the correct format.

Even, I have check that if I do a caching like commented here http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/ it works, data is downloaded and MediaPlayer can play it after.

The URLs not played are:

http://makrodigital.com:8014/forever?type=.mp3

http://makrodigital.com:8014/radioforevermusic?type=.mp3

Code:

```
private void prepareAndPlay() {     

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    player.setOnInfoListener(this);

    try {
        player.setDataSource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),Uri.parse(getURL()));
        player.prepareAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG," Setting data source " + getParam(),e);
        buildErrorPopup();
        return;
    }
}

    // In the problematic URLs it is never called
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    try {
        mp.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If alsa have test this with no luck:

```
//Setting HTTP header for fixing some issues with normal  setDataSource Header from Android
//User-Agent "iTunes" was set to force re-direct to shoutcast streaming url     
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("User-Agent", "iTunes");
player.setDataSource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Uri.parse(getParam()), headers);
```

The question is, it's any way to use MediaPlayer to play this URL directly, to avoid complexities of implements a caching that works in all possible escenarios ?

If have seen there is a Low Level Media API here, [Best practices for audio streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405017/best-practices-for-audio-streaming).

Comment: Check the logcat for anything that might indicate what is going wrong via your OnErrorListener and OnInfoListener implementations.

Comment: Avoid using `e.printStackTrace();` in android projects, instead use the android sdk provided logging class [LOG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) ... something like `Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage(), e);`

Comment: @petey , I have checked and no Error is reported neither any futher information. It is waiting to start. About .printStackTrace(), you are right, I avoid them, it was autogenerated code for the test.

Comment: Which version of android?

Comment: I have tested in Android 4.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I notice this question is rather old, but remains unanswered.  The `onPrepared()` method of your `MediaPlayer` object is never called because the data source is bad and can not prepare.  Sometimes streaming radio station links go offline for any number of reasons and it's not the fault of your code.  If a link is bad, it is bad and that is all there is.  Set up an `onErrorListener()` to watch for this and handle the error by letting the user know there is a problem and move on with your code (i.e. play the next link or exit.)